# I have deleted Redirect module and have lost alias-to-alias redirects as well as the ability to show aliases in some nodes

Tags: redirection

I uninstalled and removed the Redirect module using these commands.

```bash
vendor/bin/drush un redirect
composer remove drupal/redirect
```

This caused me to lose about 15 alias-to-alias redirects.
I have also noticed that now, if I visit /node/1 and click on a link to /node/2, its path alias (/node/my-second-node) is not used.

Would re-installing the Redirect module be enough, or must I retrieve data from a backup as well?

Comment: This is not a duplicate. Here I ask about how to revert problems from deleting it, not if deleting it can cause problems.

Comment: As said in the duplicate the information of the old aliases is lost. But it should be no problem to enter 15 alias-to-alias redirects manually in the Redirect UI once you have the module installed. Redirects from /node/1 to the current alias don't need data, this works automatically when installing the module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restore the site from a backup or replace the redirects manually after reinstalling the module.